How to fix runtime error 91 while printing ActiveWorkBook.Name VBA?
I have a macro that I've been using for years which all of a sudden started giving the 'Object variable or With block variable not set' error.
To try to isolate the issue I created this test:
Private Sub test()
    Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Sub

I'm getting the same Object error (Run-Time error '91') and cannot think of any reason this should be happening when I'm not even using a variable in the test.  I noticed it's only happening on one specific .XLS file but this file is emailed to me every month and I've used the same macro to process these files for years.  I created a new .XLS file on my desktop, same location as the problem file, and am able to print ActiveWorkbook.Name with no error.

Have you talked with the people supplying the file to see if they have changed anything on their end and if yes, what?

I didn't talk to them, but to your point I did notice something.  I posted it as an answer.  If the file comes in a similar fashion next month, I reach out to find out why this is happening.  Thank you,

I wasn't sure if I should delete this post or not but I found the answer and thought it may help someone someday.
For some reason, this file opened in protected view.  In all the years I've been doing this, I've never had this issue.  I wasn't seeing the "enable editing" prompt and didn't notice protected view.  Unprotect sheet was grayed out so I just copied the data to a new workbook and was able to run my macro.
